# Apply style on mouseover and when class variable is true

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I come from a web background, so I'm really struggling with this one.

I have a style that I need applied when both IsMouseOver is true and a class variable (called _isLinking) is true within my Linking class is true also. I have the style built and functioning with the IsMouseOver, but I'm not sure how to get the second condition with the _isLinking in there.

```
<Path.Style>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Path.Stroke" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="LightGray" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Canvas.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Path.Stroke" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="LightBlue" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Path.Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `MultiDataTrigger` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger.aspx)).

Example:

```
<Canvas>
    <Path>
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100" />
        </Path.Data>
        <Path.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Path.Stroke" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="LightGray" />
                <Style.Triggers>                            
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>                                    
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Canvas}}" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsLinking}" Value="True" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Path.Stroke" Value="Blue" />
                            <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="LightBlue" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Path.Style>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

In the above example `DataContext` is set to object of type `Linking`.

```
 this.DataContext = new Linking { IsLinking = true };
```